# Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x7f2f82ee3aa0> on Django

Tags: django, opencv3.1

**Unhandled exception occurs while passing function inside models.py in Django (installing by *pip* *install* *numpy* *django* *requests*)**

> I am trying to manipulate face detection api on web using OpenCV, Numpy and Redis.
>   But i got an exception on passing the fuctions inside the models.py
>
> I am just a newbee on Django framework and Python languages.

Here is my error while running my Django server !

> Unhandled exception in thread started by 
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/home/xyz/.xyz/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 227, in wrapper
>        fn(*args, **kwargs)
>   File "/home/xyz/.xyz/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run  autoreload.raise_last_exception()
>   File "/home/xyz/.xyz/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py",  line 250, in raise_last_exception
>     six.reraise(*_exception)
>   File "/home/xyz/.xyz/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 227, in wrapper
>      fn(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "/home/xyz/.xyz/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/**init**.py", line  27, in setup
>     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
>   File "/home/xyz/.xyz/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
>      app_config.import_models()
>     File "/home/xyz/.xyz/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
>     self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/**init**.py", line 37, in import_module  **import**(name)
>    File "/home/xyz/PycharmProjects/xyz_project/OpencvWeb/opencv_api/Face_detection/models.py", line 28, in 
>      class LFace:
>      File "/home/xyz/PycharmProjects/xyz_project/OpencvWeb/opencv_api/Face_detection/models.py", line 29, in LFace
>       def **init**(self, faceRect = LRect(), eyes=[], id = 0, mt = 0, vel = LVector(0,0)):
>   NameError: name 'LRect' is not defined

And Here is my code in models.py
This is the class for LFace

```
class LFace:
    def __init__(self, faceRect = LRect(), eyes=[], id = 0, mt = 0, vel = LVector(0,0)):
        self.face = faceRect.clone()
        self.eyes = [e.clone() for e in eyes]
        self.id = id
        self.name = ''
        self.missingTicks = mt
        self.velocity = vel
    def clone(self):
        return LFace(self.face, self.eyes, self.id)
    def setAs(self, f2):
        self.face = f2.face.clone()
        self.eyes = [e.clone() for e in f2.eyes]
        self.id = f2.id
        self.missintTicks = f2.missingTicks
        self.velocity = f2.velocity.clone()
    def dist(self, f2, scalar1 = 1.0, scalar2 = 0.2):
    #distance is defined as: center differences * scalar1 + size differences * scalar2
        d1 = self.face.center().dist(f2.face.center())
        d2 = self.face.wh().dist(f2.face.wh())
        return d1 * scalar1 + d2 * scalar2
    def interpolateTo(self, f2, t):
        self.face.interpolateTo(f2.face, t)
        self.eyes = f2.clone().eyes if t > 0.5 else []
    def getPredicted(self):
        rv = self.clone()
        p = rv.face.center()
        oldP = p.clone()
        p += self.velocity
        rv.velocity = LVector(0,0)
        rv.face.setFromCenter(p)
        return rv
```

This is the class for LRect

```
class LRect:  
        def __init__(self, x=0, y=0, w=0, h=0):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
            self.w = w
            self.h = h

        def pos(self):
            return LVector(self.x, self.y)

        def wh(self):
            return LVector(self.w, self.h)

        def hwh(self):
            return LVector(self.w, self.h) * 0.5

        def center(self):
            return (self.pos() + self.hwh())

        def toString(self):
            return '[x={0},y={1},width={2},height={3}]'.format(*self.toList())

        def __str__(self):
            return self.toString()

        def toList(self):
            return [self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h]

        def clone(self):
            return LRect(self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h)

        def setFromCenter(self, centerPoint):
            hp = self.hwh()
            self.x = centerPoint[0] - hp[0]
            self.y = centerPoint[1] - hp[1]

        def scaleWH(self, scalar):
            # scalar can be either an LVector or a number
            c = self.center()
            hwh = self.wh() * scalar
            self.w, self.h = hwh[0], hwh[1]
            self.setFromCenter(c)

        def interpolateTo(self, r2, t):
            c = self.center()
            wh = self.wh()
            c.interpolateTo(r2.center(), t)
            wh.interpolateTo(r2.wh(), t)
            self.w, self.h = wh[0], wh[1]
            self.setFromCenter(c)
```

> Please Help !!

Comment: Did you import LRect class ?

Comment: Its on the same file. i.e models.py